# Why is Dragon Ball Z's Blu-ray ending in English? Where can I find the original Japanese ending credits?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball

I saw a [DBZ ending](https://youtu.be/X92tK_N5214) on YouTube recently, and I realized that the casting is in English. Why isn't it in Japanese like in the DVD sets? Which Blu-ray set's ending is in English? It it all of them?

Where can I find the original Japanese credits in the ending?

[image]

Comment: Why would an English localized disc set not have English credits?

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ I would like to have a original Japanese credits in the ending, like in the Dragon Box I purchased years ago, but it's DVD, larger TVs doesn't maintain the quality anymore.